# How can I include RDL Reports in SharePoint Package and be able to deploy it to different servers

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

How can i package rdl reports inside SharePoint package files (wsp), And be able to change connection string later so i can deploy that package to different servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to deploying the files, you need to register them with SSRS using [ReportingService2006.CreateReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2006.reportingservice2006.createreport.aspx) and [ReportingService2006.CreateDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2006.reportingservice2006.createdatasource.aspx).

Once the Data Sources has been deployed to your Data Connections library and registered with Reporting Services, you can change it either manually or programmatically.

For details, see:

- [Automating Report Deployment with Reporting Services in SharePoint Integration Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/feldman/archive/2007/11/18/automating-report-deployment-with-reporting-services-in-sharepoint-integration-mode.aspx)
- [Deploying Reports in Integrated Mode](http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/2008/10/18/deploying-ssrs-reports-in-integrated-mode/)